# Using wp_login vs login_redirect to redirect based on user-meta

Tags: user-meta, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

I wrote a function to redirect first-time users using `login_redirect`, and it was working great. Then I changed the hook to wp_login (to get it to play well with a social login plugin), and now the function is redirecting *all users* who sign in via the `wp_login_form`.

PS: the redirect works fine when logging in via my social login plugin.

**Is there a difference between `wp_login` and `login_redirect`, or is something wrong with the conditional php?**

Here's the code:

```
//Hook was working fine when it was login_redirect
add_action( 'wp_login', __NAMESPACE__ .'\\gsc_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function gsc_login_redirect() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    //Check if a redirect parameter was passed with the url. 
    $redirect_to = isset($_GET['redirect_to'])? $_GET['redirect_to']: '';

    //Set fallback redirect
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if(!isset($redirect_to) || $redirect_to == ''){
            if (in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
                $redirect_to = admin_url();
            }
            else $redirect_to = home_url();
        }
    }

    wp_redirect( first_time_login( $redirect_to, $user) );
    exit();
}

//Redirect user if it's their first time logging in.
function first_time_login( $redirect_to, $user){
    if( $user->user_profile_setup == 'true'){ //meta is set to true after user submits form on /account-setup
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    else{
        return "/account-setup?redirect_to='". $redirect_to . "'";
    }
}
```

What's happening is *all users* are being redirected to '/account-setup', even when `$user->user_profile_setup` is "true".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$user->user_profile_setup` is the correct way to reference the meta info?

```
# does 'user_profile_setup' show up under wp_get_current_user()?
print_r(wp_get_current_user());
```

I think you mean to do:

```
function first_time_login( $redirect_to, $user){
  if( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_profile_setup', true) == 'true' ){ //edited line
    return $redirect_to;
  }
  else{
    return "/account-setup?redirect_to='". $redirect_to . "'";
  }
}
```

Assuming that

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
print_r(get_user_meta($current_user->ID));
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
  ...
  [user_profile_setup] => Array
    (
      [0] => true
    )
  ...
)
```